# Laravel Livewire Render Instance Of Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-livewire

I have instance of livewire component:

```
$component = new TableComponent(); // TableComponent is Livewire component
$component->addRow(...);
```

The issue is I can't use `@livewire('table-component')` because it would create a NEW instance that's different from my instance `$component`.

How do I render the instance that I declared `$component`?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$component = new TableComponent();
$component = $component->addRow(...);
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn’t solve the issue. The question is how do you render the $component instance in livewire?

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late answer but I encounter similar issue. This is my solution to the similar problem. The key is  `Blade::render` function. Maybe it helps.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class EditorElement implements \Stringable
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $src,
        private array $flags,
    ) {
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        $flags = var_export($this->flags, true);
        $element = <<<HTML
            <livewire:editor
                src="{$this->src}"
                :flags="{$flags}"
            />
        HTML;

        return Blade::render($element);
    }
}
```